# Generate consecutive variables and set equal to function

Tags: javascript, function

In javascript, how would one generate a sequence of `vars` and set them all equal to a specific function?

for example, I want to create 20 variables that increment by one consecutive integer:

```
var color1 = getRandomColor()
var color2 = getRandomColor()
var color3 = getRandomColor()...
```

and so on, and then set each equal to the same function

I understand generating variables could be done with the function below but how would one set search these output variables to the `getRandomColor()` function  *within*  a function?

```
function createVariables() {
    var colors = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= 20; ++i) {
        colors[i] = "color" + i;
        }
    return colors;
}
```

Comment: Your question is not so clear, can you please elaborate more. What you are looking for?

Comment: You can create an array and use `index` to access elements Why do you need to create 20 variables?

Comment: 20 variables. color[i]  where i = 1-20 and each variable is equal to `getRandomColor() `

Comment: How would do this with an array?

Comment: `var colors = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
        colors[i] = getRandomColor();
        }`

Comment: @Satpal He doesn't want it to look like this. Anyways, that what he want is not actually possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create properties dynamically using Bracket notation.

```js
//Define a object
window.colors = {}
for (var i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
  window.colors["color" + i] = i; //getRandomColor();
}
console.log(window.colors.color0, window.colors)
```

However I would recommend you to create an array and use its index

```js
var colors = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
  colors[i] = i; //getRandomColor();
}
console.log(colors[0], colors)
```